# Automate conversion of text to PNG (or another file format with transparency)?

Tags: text, png, imagemagick

I need to take a list of words and create a PNG file of each, with a transparent background.

I’d like my script to allow for adjustable opacity of the foreground, but I can probably also do it after the fact when the images get imported into Matlab.

I imagine this is doable with ImageMagick and have installed that on my Mac. If someone can give me the one line I’d need to turn a word into a PNG (the word can be the filename too) in Perl or Python, I can probably figure out the rest of the scripting.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138804/how-to-transform-a-text-file-into-a-picture Multiline methods described there.

Answer (score 7):

I found [this](http://www.linuxandlife.com/2012/09/how-to-create-simple-text-image-with.html) to be applicable to your question:

```
convert -size 560x85 xc:transparent -font Palatino-Bold -pointsize 72 -fill black -draw "text 20,55 'Linux and Life'" linuxandlife.png
```

Output:

[image]

- size 560x85 : the size (width x height) of the image
- xc:transparent : xc means X window color, use "transparent" to get a transparent background
- fond Palatino-Bold : the font of the text ( type "identify -list font" in the terminal to know all the supported fonts)
- pointsize 72 : the size of the text
- fill black : the color of the text ( check this link to know the names of the supported colors)
- draw "text 20,55 'Linux and Life'" : the position of the text and the text itself
- linuxandlife.png : the output image

Comment: Thanks, I used draw and its sub option text.  However I went through great pain finding that it didn't directly support multiple lines or \t\r\n characters.  convert threw errors that didn't directly point at -draw's dislike of \r in the string.  Instead one must create multiple -draw entries with separate x,y coordinates to create multi-line text after removing \t\r\n characters.  Or use -caption or -annotate options instead of -draw which directly support multi-line.

Comment: Article archive @ https://web.archive.org/web/20160331152440/http://www.linuxandlife.com/2012/09/how-to-create-simple-text-image-with.html

Answer (score 0):

[Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) (better known as pylab) would work great for this. Assuming ImageMagick is installed this script should work. (tested on Ubuntu 9.10)

```
import pylab as py, os

W = ['cat','dog','mouse']

for word in W:
    py.clf()
    ax = py.axes(alpha=1.0) 
    py.text(0,.5,word)
    py.axis('off')
    py.savefig("%s.png"%word)
    os.system('convert -trim %s.png %s.png' % (word,word))
```

This creates three files on my system `dog.png`, `cat.png` and `mouse.png` all cropped with a transparent background.

Comment: Sweet, I’ll give it a try this weekend!

Comment: If this answer is what you were looking for, please mark it or let us know what else you need!